# Number of connect() calls = TCP SYN segments?

Tags: networking

I can running a system call logging utility. Now the number of TCP SYN packets I see are not equal to the number of connect() system calls I record? What can be the reason for this?
Do any other system calls call connect internally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are all sorts of reasons.

If a connect() fails because of an unroutable address, it may never generate a SYN packet at all (e.g. arp timeout). Likewise if connect fails with some other error (e.g. invalid parameters).

The SYN packet might go on an interface you're not looking at (e.g. localhost)

The kernel will retry; if there is no reply to a request, it will try again (probably several times) before eventually returning a timeout.

Comment: I see SYN segments before the connect call time...What can be the reason for this?